# Remove drop shadow from the image

Tags: inkscape, drop-shadow

[image]

This is a chess piece and i want to remove the shadowy effect in this. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: what's the original image format, vector or raster? Can you [edit] the question to add more details? Check [ask] for more info

Comment: The orignial image format is a .png file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the image been drawn with a drop-shadow filter applied, you could have removed it. To do that you'd select the chess piece, then from the filters menu and choose Remove Filters. That would remove all the filters.

Unfortunately you don't really have an SVG drawing at all. What you have is a raster image of the chess piece wrapped in an SVG file. I.e.

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <image id="image0" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;*raster image data*"/>
</svg>
```

There's not much you can do here other than redraw the image you want from scratch in the editor as SVG.

Comment: Emm. The point is i didn't create this image. And i tried removing filters. It doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Sorry. It seems we can't insert SVG files :(

Comment: oops i dont understand that a bit :( https://gofile.io/d/jhXtoc i have uploaded the file here black pawn

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i converted the PNG to SVG. Would be grateful in case you could help me out with the drawing.

Comment: If you really can't face drawing it yourself in Inkscape from scratch, you could always try to convert it to SVG via [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). You might then be able to remove the shadow in inkscape if you did that.

Comment: Will see what needs to be done. Thanks for the kind help